# Diagnostic Codes Disabled In Dialer?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, phone-app, dialer-codes

I have a Huawei Ascend Y300 running on Jelly Bean and I can't get any diagnostic code to work on the dialer... The only thing that works is the code for displaying the IMEI: `*#06#`

Every time I enter a diagnostic code like `*#*#4636#*#*` or anything else, it merely continues to display the dialer. :-/

I've tried looking for the stock Jelly Bean dialer but I haven't had any luck. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you try this code `*#*#2846579#*#*`. Does it work on your phone?

Comment: @geffchang: Yes! I got a Testing menu with 2 options:

MMITest_II
ProjectMenu

Comment: Well then, it looks like there's nothing wrong with your phone or your dialer. Maybe your phone just doesn't support the `*#*#4636#*#*` code. Some diagnostic codes are for specific phones only.

Comment: Well... I thought it was odd that only one code was working. None of the other codes work from these lists, except for the one you mentioned: http://plusdroid.com/Blogandnews/we-spill-the-beans-of-jellybean-android-secret-dial-codes-list/ http://askvg.com/google-android-hidden-secret-codes/

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `*#*#6130#*#*`

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your phone does not support the code. If you look at one of the comments in the [askvg link](http://www.askvg.com/google-android-hidden-secret-codes/) you shared in the comment, one user says: `LCD TEST Does not work for Galaxy S2`. However, another user replied that it is supported, but with a different code.